# iPhone:How to add "Degree" symbol in UILabel string text?

Tags: iphone

I want to include "degree" symbol for weather report as 45 degree C. How to add degree symbol in string to include that UILabel?

If anybody knows it, please share to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Shift-option-8?

Comment: Not sure why this is in question form, but it indeed is the answer.

Comment: This is enough...

Answer (score 5):

In Swift

```
cell.lblTemperature.text = NSString(format:"23%@", "\u{00B0}") as String
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"80\u00b0c"];
    [attributedString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-light" size:10.0]
                                      , NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName : @22} range:NSMakeRange(2, 2)];
    //asign this as a 
examplelabel.attributedtext = attributedString;
```

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 8.0:
Press  Control+Command+Space Bar or Xcode->Edit->Emoji & Symbols, later search the degree symbols from pop-up screen.
You can easily add UILabel or TextView components.